# Expression is not assignable error with CGRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

I'm trying to create a `CGRect` property.

```
@property (nonatomic) CGRect myRect;
```

Then later on, I set the frame:

```
self.myRect = self.frame;
self.myRect.size.height = 10; // Error
```

I get an error saying "Expression is not assignable". Why do I get that? Can't I change the size of a `CGRect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way.

```
_myRect = self.frame;
_myRect.size.height = 10;
```

Comment: I can't create 1 that will be accessible throughout the class?

Comment: Thanks!! That worked!! Why can't I use self instead?

Comment: If it help make it accepted. Please check this answer for more clarification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860755/how-to-gain-assignment-access-to-cgrect-elements-when-the-cgrect-is-an-instance

Comment: I was waiting for the timer to finish :)

Answer (score 1):

`self.myRect.size.height = 10` is equivalent to `[ self myRect ].size.height = 10`

You must read the CGRect property, modify it, then write it back:

```
CGRect r = [ self myRect ] ;
// modify r here
[ self setMyRect:r ] ;
```

or:

```
CGRect r = self.myRect ;
// modify r here
self.myRect = r ;
```